# Redirect Vue application with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, redirect, vuejs3

I am trying to redirect the Vue.js application with Laravel's `redirect()` method but seemingly it doesn't work with Vue.js. Currently I am returning a redirect in one of my controllers in this way:

`return redirect(url);`

The redirection works when I call the endpoint from Chrome, but it doesn't work when the endpoint is called from Vue.js.

Comment: This approach is not good, because in VueJS redirection has own way!!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the last comment You should try another type of return.

for example.

```
public function YourFunction()
    {
     return view('url');
    }
```